# SQL New column with most recent different value in a column of interest

Tags: sql, lag, difference

I am using SQL in Cognos.
If I have a column of dates and field of interest, how can I make a new column where the most recent different value is brought forward for each row. I don't believe I can use lag to do this. Thank you for any ideas.

```
Example:
    Date    Field   DesiredNew 
    1/9/1994    D   C
    1/8/1994    D   C
    1/7/1994    D   C
    1/6/1994    C   B
    1/5/1994    B   A
    1/4/1994    B   A
    1/3/1994    B   A
    1/2/1994    A   
    1/1/1994    A
```

Answer (score 0):

This is just a quick idea that crossed mind.

If you could add two columns (do not display them just use them for the logic) this way:

```
Date    Field   DesiredNew FieldSeq DesicredNewSeq
1/7/1994    D   C          4        3
1/6/1994    C   B          3        2
```

Hence, you can use function CASE to test number and assign letters.

Answer (score 0):

**Overview**

The gist of the solution is a 2-step approach.

First, consider the original records ordered according to `Date` and consecutive records with the same `Field` value being grouped, noting the maximum and minimum dates of each of said groups. The generated resultset"s records describe maximal date intervals within which the field value does not change (this selection is encapsulated in the view `vtest_lag` in the sql example below).

Next self-join this new resultset with a lag of 1 on one of its date column. This way adjoining intervals are paired in the final resultset, allowing to update `Field` values as desired.

**Caveats**

1. The solution assumes no duplicate dates in the original data
2. The solution is not concerned with efficiency

**SQL solution**

This self-contained example is agnostic to sql dialects apart from oracle's  `rownum` pseudocolumn supplying the ordinal number of a record in a resultset. There are equivalent features in other sql flavors.

***Part 1/2: Setup***

```
create table test_lag (
    t_date        date
  , field         varchar2(10)
  , desirednew    varchar2(10)
  , computednew   varchar2(10)
);

insert into test_lag values ( to_date ( '01/09/1994', 'DD/MM/YYYY' ), 'D', 'C'  , null );
insert into test_lag values ( to_date ( '01/08/1994', 'DD/MM/YYYY' ), 'D', 'C'  , null );
insert into test_lag values ( to_date ( '01/07/1994', 'DD/MM/YYYY' ), 'D', 'C'  , null );
insert into test_lag values ( to_date ( '01/06/1994', 'DD/MM/YYYY' ), 'C', 'B'  , null );
insert into test_lag values ( to_date ( '01/05/1994', 'DD/MM/YYYY' ), 'B', 'A'  , null );
insert into test_lag values ( to_date ( '01/04/1994', 'DD/MM/YYYY' ), 'B', 'A'  , null );
insert into test_lag values ( to_date ( '01/03/1994', 'DD/MM/YYYY' ), 'B', 'A'  , null );
insert into test_lag values ( to_date ( '01/02/1994', 'DD/MM/YYYY' ), 'A', null , null );
insert into test_lag values ( to_date ( '01/01/1994', 'DD/MM/YYYY' ), 'A', null , null );
```

***Part 2/2: Update***

View `vtest_lag` encapsulates the query to provide the data for the update statement.

```
  create or replace view vtest_lag as
  select emb.*
       , rownum seq
    from (
              select *
                from (
                          select sysdate    t_date1
                               , null       field1
                               , t_date     t_date2
                               , field      field2
                            from test_lag
                           where t_date = (select max(t_date) from test_lag)
                       union all
                          select t_date     t_date1
                               , field      field1
                               , to_date( '01/01/1900', 'DD/MM/YYYY' )
                                            t_date2
                               , null       field2
                            from test_lag
                           where t_date = (select min(t_date) from test_lag)
                       union all
                          select po1.t_date    t_date1
                               , po1.field     field1
                               , po2.t_date    t_date2
                               , po2.field     field2
                            from (
                                   select po1_base.*
                                        , rownum    seq
                                     from (
                                               select *
                                                 from test_lag
                                             order by t_date desc
                                          ) po1_base
                                 ) po1
                            join (
                                   select po2_base.*
                                        , rownum     seq
                                     from (
                                               select *
                                                 from test_lag
                                             order by t_date desc
                                          ) po2_base
                                 ) po2
                              on po2.seq = po1.seq + 1
                           where po1.field <> po2.field
                     )
            order by t_date1 desc
         ) emb
         ;

  update test_lag trg
     set trg.computednew = (select v2.field2 from vtest_lag v1 join vtest_lag v2 on v2.seq = v1.seq+1 where trg.t_date <= v1.t_date2 and trg.t_date >= v2.t_date1)
       ;
```

Comment: Thank you. My data is more complicated and does include repeated dates, with another sequence field. I will look over your answer though and greatly appreciate it. Since it doesn't see like a compact solution exists, I may import the data to R where I can do the manipulation easily using:

Comment: out.i <- list("vector")
for(i in 1:nrow(dat)){
  for(j in 1:nrow(dat)){
  
    if( (dat[i,2] == dat[max(i, j), 2]) == FALSE ){
      out.i[[i]] <- data.frame(dat[i,], dat[max(i, j),2])  
      break
    } else {
      out.i[[i]] <- data.frame(dat[i,], dat[max(i, j),2])  
    }

  }
  
}
outi <- do.call(rbind, out.i)
colnames(outi)[3] <- "FieldNew"
outi[3] <- ifelse(outi[,2] == outi[,3], "", as.character(outi[,3]))